# Jenkins heap issue

Tags: jenkins, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am getting a below error when running maven build. I dont take the job is taking much memory but it fails with heap error just before archiving the artifacts.

[INFO] Final Memory: 118M/9062M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
FATAL: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I have tried increasing the memory to 8192m in job, setting java_opts, updated memory parameters in jenkins xml but no luck. I am using a windows machine. Same build works fine in another server.

Comment: it depends where you run this command on master or agent